# Biblatex time field in addition to date

Tags: biblatex

Biblatex's `date` and `urldate` only reference the day that the entry was made/accesses on.

Is there a way to add the *time* to a bibliography entry as well?

Any tips welcome!

Comment: Recent versions of `biblatex` (in combination with Biber) allow users to extend the data model with custom fields. Thus one could introduce a field `time`. Then one can redefine the formatting instruction for printing a date to include the time. The interesting thing would be how to change the format of the time using various standards (24hours, pm/am,...).

Comment: It would be nice if I could somehow reuse all the functionality of `date` type in my `time` type and then add additional functionality for rendering time.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the trick for url's in my bibliography

`lastchecked="\today"`,
How about trying to use the

`\currenttime`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: I am not asking. I am more suggestion +drozzy. Is this the wrong place to do so?

Comment: @agerom No, this isn't the wrong place. Perhaps you can add what's needed to get `\currenttime`